# How do I know the "default include directories", "default link directories" and "default link libraries" of gcc, g++/c++ in Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: c++, gcc

For the following 3 compile cases :

```
gcc -o helloc hello.c                    (1)

g++ -o hellocpp hello.cpp                (2)

c++ -o hellocpp hello.cpp                (3)
```

how do I know the "default include directories", "default link directories" and "default link libraries" in each case ? I am using gcc 4.5.2 in a 32 bit Ubuntu 11.04 environment.

For case (1), is gcc using the standard C libraries or the GNU C libraries ? Is there difference between the two C libraries ?

Comparing cases (2) and (3), is there any difference in the "default link libraries" used by the compiler ? Are they using the standard C++ libraries or the GNU C++ libraries ? What is the difference between the two C++ libraries ?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Lawrence Tsang

Comment: include headers path http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988779/gcc-how-to-ignore-standard-include-paths || libraries path http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922949/how-to-print-the-ldlinker-search-path

Comment: For C:

    gcc -xc -E -v -

    For C++:

    gcc -xc++ -E -v -

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Say `gcc -v`, or `g++ -v` to print out verbose information about the environment.

E.g. for me this says:

```
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2
 /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/i686-pc-linux-gnu
 /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/backward
 /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/include-fixed
 /usr/include
```

Also try `gcc -dumpspecs` to see details about the invoked tools in the tool chain.

Comment: This needs a file to compile. So just running `g++ -v` wont work. It needs to be `g++ -v somefile.cpp`

Comment: As an [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17940271/287933) you can try `echo | gcc -E -Wp,-v -`.

Answer (score 12):

Kerrek SB's answer doesn't quite work for me on Ubuntu 12.04, but this seems to work:

`cpp -v`

Toward the bottom I get this:

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include
/usr/local/include
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include-fixed
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/include
End of search list.
```

Answer (score 1):

As another alternative you can use this command:

```
echo | gcc -E -Wp,-v -
```

Since messages of gcc are printed as stderr you may redirect it to stdin for further processing (e.g. `sed`, `grep`, `awk`, ...)

```
echo | gcc -E -Wp,-v - 2>&1 | grep lib
```