# local installation of gcc in home directory

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

my question is: how do I make sure gcc automatically finds the right include files by default? what I did is compile gcc modules branch with --prefix=$HOME/.local and it worked. next thing to try it out with the next requirement: install "build2" with that new compiler. so I do

```
PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/.local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.0.0/:$PATH" LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/p/.local/lib64" sh build2-install-0.13.0.sh --sudo false $HOME/.local/
```

and I get lots of errors about missing header-files, like array, stddef.h, sstream, bits/c++config.h and limits.h

adding `-I$HOME/.local/{include/c++/11.0.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu,include/c++/11.0.0,lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.0.0/include,lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.0.0/include-fixed}` to the g++ options fixes those, but I'd like to have those paths built into my compiler. how do I do that? where in the gcc sources do I have to change something to make gcc aware of where it had installed all those headers?

edit: the fix for my problem was simple: problem is that ~/.local/bin was symlink to ~/bin, so I only need to rm that, move ~/bin in its place and optionally create a symlink from ~/.local/bin to ~/bin. my question still stands though, maybe a bit more academic now: how do I force gcc to look for headers at a certain location by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), you have to set some of the [implicit variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html):

```
$ export CXX=/path/to/your/installation/bin/g++
$ export CC=/path/to/your/installation/bin/gcc
$ export LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -L /path/to/your/installation/lib64 \
                  -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/path/to/your/installation/lib64"
```

where `/path/to/your/installation` is where you installed `gcc`.

Note that I export also `CC` which defines the C compiler. Also, `export LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} ...` prevents to overwrite previous settings of `LDFLAGS`.

**Addition**

The OP asks

> how do I force gcc to look for headers at a certain location by default

`gcc` searches the headers of the standard library in its installation folder*. You can explicitly check this as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920640/how-do-i-know-the-default-include-directories-default-link-directories-and).
So there is not need to add `-I /path/to/your/installation` to use the headers of the local installation.

Anyway, from the [man pages of g++](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/g++.1.html):

> CPATH specifies a list of directories to be searched as if
> specified with -I, but after any paths given with -I options on the command line.

Exporting `CPATH=...` sets a default directory to search for headers.

---

<sub>*As noted in the comments, it appears that gcc searches its library in a path relative to the location of the executable g++/gcc, *resolving eventual symlinks*.</sub>

Comment: yes, my search on stack-overflow also resulted in the advise to execute gcc and g++ with full path to the binary, so it finds its headers. sadly build2 explicitely executes `gmake -j4 -f ./bootstrap.gmake CXX=g++`, and I cannot change that easily without failing checksum test. what I want is everytime this user executes g++ it should use the one in homedirectory, without the need to give the full path. any idea where in the gcc sources I can alter how the program finds its own binary, so it doesn't need to rely on that?

Comment: @user11566470 uhm, in principle unix [searches the executables from ```$PATH```](https://superuser.com/questions/238987/how-does-unix-search-for-executable-files). Are you sure that $PATH is set correctly? For example, if you do ```export PATH=...(your string above)``` and then ```g++ -v```, do you execute your local installation?

Comment: thanks to you I got reminded how to fix it as I had similar problems in past: many unix programs get into trouble if the path to the executable consists of symlinks or even worse hardlinks...

Comment: "gcc searches the headers of the standard library in its installation folder." is wrong! `cd; rm bin;mv .local/bin/ . ;ln -sf $HOME/bin .local/ ;$HOME/.local/bin/g++ -v delme.h` proves gcc isn't making use of --prefix but instead resolves symlinks in its binary's path and suddenly believes to have been installed in $HOME. I get `ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/p/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.0.0/include"` for example!

Comment: @user11566470 I mean, if you mess up the installation, you cannot pretend it still works...

Comment: sorry if I made the impression as if I would have such an expectation. I should put it differently then: in your answer please add the info that having a symlink of non-equivalent depth instead of the directory "bin" or inside the path "lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.0.0" will mess up the installation! or better yet maybe point out where this is warned about in gcc instructions?

Comment: Note, that presented solution works with `cmake` too.