# Compiler ignores my includes -I for new library version

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors, compilation, include

**I think that this question is not specifically on OpenCV**, it seems more an include problem, so please read it even if you don't know the library.

There is  an old version of a library (OpenCV) that's installed in `/usr/local` on the remote machine where I'm working on and where I don't have `sudo` access.

I've installed an updated version in my local environment `/home/spm1428/local` and I'm compiling it by using `-I/home/spm1428/local/include/opencv` and `-I/home/spm1428/local/include/opencv2`.

However, in a file where `#include "opencv/opencv.hpp"` I get this error:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:77:0,
                 from /home/spm1428/CloudCache/Utilities/Utility.hpp:11,
                 from ../Descriptors/Descriptor.cpp:17:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp:165:25: error: redeclaration of ‘IMREAD_UNCHANGED’
```

It's an error given by the old version of the library installed in `/usr/local`, but I told him to use the local version using `-I`!

**So it seems that the compiler ignores my `-I` directives and instead gives the priority to `/usr/local/include`**

Why this happens?

If you wonder the whole compiling command is:

```
g++ -DCC_DISABLE_CUDA -I/home/spm1428/CloudCache -I/home/spm1428/local/include/opencv -I/home/spm1428/local/include/opencv2 -I/usr/include/boost -I/home/spm1428/vlfeat -O3 -g -Wall -c -fopenmp -std=c++11   -c -o Descriptor.o ../Descriptors/Descriptor.cpp
```

This error happens both using `#include <opencv2/core.hpp>` and `include "opencv2/core.hpp"`.

**UPDATE OF NEW ERROR:**

Changing: `#incldue <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` to `#include "opencv2/core.hpp"`
`#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"` solved the problem for some reason. However, now when I compile:

```
g++ -DCC_DISABLE_CUDA -I/home/spm1428/local/include -I/home/spm1428/CloudCache -I/home/spm1428/local/include/opencv -I/home/spm1428/local/include/opencv2 -I/usr/include/boost -I/home/spm1428/vlfeat -O3 -g -Wall -c -fopenmp -std=c++11   -c -o SIFTOpenCV.o ../Descriptors/SIFTOpenCV.cpp
```

I get this error:

```
../Descriptors/SIFTOpenCV.cpp:31:9: error: ‘class cv::Feature2D’ has no member named ‘detectAndCompute’
   sift->detectAndCompute(img, cv::Mat(), pts, descriptors);
```

`SIFTOpenCV.cpp` includes `SIFTOpenCV.hpp`, which includes `#include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"`. I think that this error is related somehow to the previous one.

The weirdest thing is that this compiles correctly on my local machine (where I have `sudo` access and I installed it `/usr/local`)

This is the class `SIFTOpenCV.hpp`:

```
#include "Descriptors/Descriptor.hpp"
#include <opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp>

namespace cc{
    class SIFTOpenCV : public Descriptor{
    public:
        SIFTOpenCV(int nFeatures=0, int nOctaveLayers=3, double contrastThreshold=0.04, double edgeThreshold=10, double sigma=1.6);
        void mapParams(std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::string>> &params);
        void ComputeDescriptors(cv::Mat &img, cv::Mat1f &descriptors);
    private:
        cv::Ptr<cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT> sift;
        int nFeatures, nOctaveLayers;
        double contrastThreshold, edgeThreshold, sigma;
    };
}
```

While `Descriptor.hpp`:

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <map>

namespace cc{
    class Descriptor{
    public:
        virtual void mapParams(std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::string>> &params) = 0;
        virtual void ComputeDescriptors(cv::Mat &img, cv::Mat1f &descriptors) = 0;
        virtual void ComputeDescriptors(const std::string &fileName, const std::string &imgExt, cv::Mat1f &descriptor);
        virtual void ComputeDescriptors(const std::string &dirPath, const std::string &imgExt, std::vector<cv::Mat1f> &descriptors);
        void setResizeDim(const size_t resizeDim);
        void setSamples (const size_t samples);
        void setOMP(const bool omp);
        virtual ~Descriptor();
    private:
        void ComputeDescriptorsRange(const std::vector<std::string> &files, std::vector<cv::Mat1f> &descriptors, const int start, const int finish, size_t errors);
        size_t resizeDim = 0;   //comput full-size image
        int samples = 0;
        bool omp = true;
    };
}
```

Comment: can you please post the subfoldernames and filenames of `/home/spm1428/local/include/opencv`?

Comment: please try `-I/home/spm1428` instead

Comment: @Micka thanks for you first comment, I updated the question

Comment: @Micka Adding `-I/home/spm1428` gives the same result unfortunately

Comment: since you `#include "opencv2/core.hpp` your include directory given to the compiler must the be the folder where `opencv2/` is inside, since the included file will be searched in a opencv2 subfolder of the known directories. At least that's my guess, I'm not so familiar with g++ According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988779/gcc-how-to-ignore-standard-include-paths the -I pathes should be used before standard pathes. You could try `--nostdinc` if that's ok for you.

Comment: sorry, told you the wrong directory. Please try: `-I/home/spm1428/local/include/`

Comment: @Micka Same error using `g++ -DCC_DISABLE_CUDA -I/home/spm1428/local/include -I/home/spm1428/CloudCache -I/home/spm1428/local/include/opencv -I/home/spm1428/local/include/opencv2 -I/usr/include/boost -I/home/spm1428/vlfeat -O3 -g -Wall -c -fopenmp -std=c++11   -c -o Descriptor.o ../Descriptors/Descriptor.cpp` ...

Comment: @Micka and both using `<>` and `" "` for include

Comment: Your are including <opencv2/opencv.hpp>, therefore your -I directive should point to the path in which the opencv2 directory is. In your post, the command shows -I/home/spm1428/local/include/opencv2. Shouldn't this be -I/home/spm1428/local/include/ ?

Comment: @Ben I've showed in my comment before the last one that the error doesn't change if I add `-I/home/spm1428/local/include`

Comment: @Micka Please give a look at **UPDATE OF NEW ERROR**

Comment: @Ben Please give a look at **UPDATE OF NEW ERROR**

Comment: can't you just ask your admin to get sudo rights or let him rename or remove your old openCV stuff? If not, have a look at both versions, which files are present etc. For exmaple, SIFT is removed from newer openCV versions by default etc...

Comment: @Micka I updated the question including the header files and how the `detectAndCompute` is called. I've checked `/usr/local/include/opencv2/features2d.hpp` and there is no `detectAndCompute` so it's clear that the compiler is looking at that version (while it exists in `/home/spm1428/local/include/opencv2/features2d.hpp`

Comment: If you are keen to using CMake, I had the same problem before (two versions of OpenCV installed, the wrong one was found by cmake). 

By setting set(OpenCV_DIR "/home/spm1428/local/include/") before the usual line find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED ), the problem was solved. The rest of the cmake script can then use ${OpenCV_LIBS} (and you can print it to verify that the correct libs are being used for compilation

Comment: @Ben This is a makefile-based project

Comment: Anyway, perhaps you should try it with a toy example just to make sure that your user-space openCV version is correctly working ... and if it is compiling properly and linking with the right lib, check the command generated by the script ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself: executing `cpp -v` returned me:

```
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include
 /home/spm1428/local/include
 ...
```

This means that using `-I/home/spm1428/local/include` was ignored because already included, but the priority was given to the old version in `/usr/local/include`.

Installing OpenCV in a new local directory and include it with `-I` gave the priority to the new version and solved the problem.