# Force GCC to use specific include file

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I have two versions of boost installed, one in `~/local_opt/` and one in `/usr/include`. I would like to use the former one, after it provides some newer functions. Thus I am compiling my program with

```
g++ -I/home/<>/local_opt/boost/include main.cpp
```

Nevertheless it fails with

```
/home/<>/local_opt/boost/include/boost/math/interpolators/cubic_b_spline.hpp:25:69: fatal error: boost/math/interpolators/detail/cubic_b_spline_detail.hpp: No such file or directory
```

Thus I assume that it still tries to use the boost functions in `/usr/include`, and not my own version of boost. Why? How can I override the search path properly?

Comment: Use `g++ -H` to understand what headers are included

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2988825/1729784

Comment: Er... what? Doesn't the error show that the version in `~/local_opt/` *is* used, but there's an error somewhere in there?

Comment: I told the file including `cubic_b_spline.hpp` to use that specific file by using the full path, but apparently the included file in `cubic_b_spline.hpp` is looked for in the standard include path

Comment: Okay, then you have two issues. First, fix your code to include Boost headers normally. Second, get your local Boost headers properly included with `-I`. You specify `-I/home/<>/local_opt/boost/include` and the error is about `boost/math/interpolators/detail/cubic_b_spline_detail.hpp`, so the obvious first question for that: does `/home/<>/local_opt/boost/include/boost/math/interpolators/detail/cubic_b_spline_detail.hpp` really exist? If it does, then the obvious second question for that: is there a typo in the `-I` option somewhere? Can you copy and paste the exact paths?

Comment: Yes, that file exists, the solution from @DaBler fixes my problem

Comment: That's very surprising. `-nostdinc` shouldn't generally work, as your program almost certainly still requires standard library headers, as does Boost. You're not dealing with a custom libc, just a third-party library. If it works, fine, but beware that you may well run into problems down the road.

Comment: @hvd: How should I then include my local boost headers properly? The boost files link internally to other boost files via `boost/...`, so I basically have to tell the compiler to only use boost files from `~/local_opt/boost`. Is there a better way?

Comment: @arc_lupus Telling the compiler to use Boost files from `~/local_opt/boost` with `-I` should be enough. Telling the compiler to *only* use Boost files from `~/local_opt/boost` shouldn't be (and normally isn't) necessary, because the ones from `~/local_opt/boost` take precedence. If they link internally to one another via `boost/...`, that still respects `-I` options, so would still prefer your local version.

Comment: @hvd: But exactly that did not work, thus my question here

Comment: @arc_lupus Yes, hence my comments to try to figure out why it's not working. It should, and I've definitely done that myself.

Comment: What else could I do to narrow the problem down?

Comment: @arc_lupus Basile Starynkevitch's suggestion of `g++ -H` is one way of confirming your suspicion that versions in `/usr/include` are used. To actually fix it, after checking that the `-I` path and your local Boost directory match, personally, I'd probably run `g++` under `strace -f -e file` to get a complete list of all files `g++` and its subprocesses attempt to access, look for `cubic_b_spline_detail.hpp` in there.

Comment: That is strange, some files from `boost/math` come from `usr/include`, some from the local installation (according to `g++ -H`)