# How to prevent multiple versions of Boost on gcc search path?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, boost

I'm compiling a program that uses Boost on a shared cluster. I have my own copy of gcc and most programs and libs I use in my home directory, including Boost 1.81.0. The cluster has Boost 1.66 in /usr/local/include. gcc seems to prefer these files over my local ones in some instances, leading to errors. How can I fix this?

This is the current include search list:
(Edited to show the effect of `-I/home/charlesprior/include` )

```
GNU C++23 (GCC) version 12.1.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 12.1.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version none
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/charlesprior/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/home/charlesprior/include"
  as it is a non-system directory that duplicates a system directory
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/charlesprior/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../include/c++/12.1.0
 /home/charlesprior/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../include/c++/12.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
 /home/charlesprior/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../include/c++/12.1.0/backward
 /home/charlesprior/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/include
 /usr/local/include
 /home/charlesprior/include
 /home/charlesprior/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

If I use `-I/home/charlesprior/include` (which is what I did in the example above) to try and force that to the top, gcc ignores the duplicate. If I use `-I/some/other/dir/include` where that includes Boost, everything compiles fine. I want to not have to do this and just make gcc use the include files in my home directory. An example of the type of error I get is:

```
In file included from /home/charlesprior/include/boost/histogram/detail/detect.hpp:11,
                 from /home/charlesprior/include/boost/histogram/axis/traits.hpp:12,
                 from /home/charlesprior/include/boost/histogram/indexed.hpp:12,
                 from /home/charlesprior/include/boost/histogram/algorithm/empty.hpp:11,
                 from /home/charlesprior/include/boost/histogram/algorithm.hpp:15,
                 from /home/charlesprior/include/boost/histogram.hpp:27,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/boost/mp11/function.hpp: In substitution of ‘template<class ... T> using variant_ca_base = boost::variant2::detail::variant
_ca_base_impl<std::integral_constant<bool, (static_cast<bool>(std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value) ... && static_cast<bool>(std::is_copy_assi
gnable<T>::value) ...)>::value, std::integral_constant<bool, (static_cast<bool>(std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value) ... && (static_cast<
bool>(std::is_trivially_copy_constructible<T>::value) ... && static_cast<bool>(std::is_trivially_copy_assignable<T>::value) ...))>::value, T .
..> [with T = {T ...}]’:
/home/charlesprior/include/boost/variant2/variant.hpp:1449:96:   required from here
/usr/local/include/boost/mp11/function.hpp:97:77: error: invalid use of pack expansion expression
```

where you can see that gcc included a file from /usr/local/include, leading to errors.

Comment: Do you have `/home/charlesprior/include/boost/mp11/function.hpp` ?

Comment: This issue is related to build process since this decides what include paths are feed to compiler. What are you using as a build manager (or build manager generator)? `make`, `cmake`, `ninja`, `bazel`, some IDE specific project file, .... . Or maybe you are building this manually?

Comment: I couldn't resist: putting up a sign might help https://imgur.com/a/yl8DC4u

Comment: Yes mp11/function.hpp exists.

Comment: I’m using make. I have a pretty simple Makefile. It just specifies a target for every object and then a target for the binary. I don’t need to add any include or library search paths since everything is in the system search paths for my compiler.

Comment: If you have multiple boosts dwelling in your compiler's baked in include paths, nothing is going to fix that, except ignoring them all: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2988825/85371

Comment: *"I have my own copy of gcc"* - where did you get it? If you are using cross-compiler then it should not pull any stuff from `/usr`.

Comment: Oh you have /home/charlesprior/include *after*  /usr/local/include in your search list. How did this ever happen? This doesn't look good at all and will lead to things mixed up. You **must** get /home/charlesprior/include on top. You say "If I use -I/home/charlesprior/include to try and force that to the top, gcc ignores the duplicate. " I have no idea what this means. Please show your gcc messages **with** -I/home/charlesprior/include as the first argument.

Comment: @user7860670 I built it myself

Comment: @n.m. Edited post. Yes I thought that the order of the directories is the problem. But I have no idea how it happened and no idea how to fix it.

Comment: "as it is a non-system directory that duplicates a system directory". So that's your problem. You have built gcc this way. Can you show how you configured it? It is a **very very bad idea** to have duplicate header files in *system* include directories so your best bet is to either build your gcc such that it does not use /home/charlesprior/include, or move **everything** the heck outta there.

Comment: @n.m. Here’s the output of `gcc -v`: ```Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/charlesprior/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/home/charlesprior --with-gmp=/home/charlesprior --with-mpfr=/home/charlesprior --with-mpc=/home/charlesprior --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 12.1.0 (GCC)```

Comment: The only configuration option I can see that alters the order of include directories is `--with-local-prefix` and that seems like it would do more harm than good?

Comment: OK so you've got your home dir as yot prefix. DON'T DO THAT. Use `--prefix=/home/charlesprior/gcc-12.1.0` otherwise you will end up with a mess.

Comment: CMake has a special flag to deal with this: `Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS`, https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html . C++ will be superseded one day, and still then Boost will be a headache.

Comment: @alfC Since posting this question I switched my build system to cmake in the hopes of taking advantage of FindBoost. This flag only affects where cmake looks for the boost include files. If you specify the required version to match what's in my home directory, it finds the correct path (`/home/charlesprior/include`) anyway, but doesn't do anything to make the compiler prioritize this. My solution was to use try_compile with a small test program to see if the right version was being included. I've updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a system directory is in the wrong place in your include search order, the only way to put it first is by using the flag `-isystem` (as opposed to `-I`). https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html

You can use CMake to try and get this right:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(
        BoostProject
        VERSION 1.0
        LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

find_package(Boost 1.81.0 REQUIRED)

message(STATUS "Boost include dirs: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
try_compile(
        CORRECT_BOOST_VERSION
        SOURCES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/test_boost_version.cpp"
        COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "-DBOOST_FOUND=${Boost_VERSION_MACRO}" "-I ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

if (NOT CORRECT_BOOST_VERSION)
    message(STATUS "Boost version in standard include paths is not correct.")
    message(CHECK_START "Attempting to declare ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} as a system include directory.")
    try_compile(
            SECOND_BOOST_TEST
            SOURCES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/test_boost_version.cpp"
            COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "-DBOOST_FOUND=${Boost_VERSION_MACRO}" "-isystem ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}"
            OUTPUT_VARIABLE TRY_COMPILE_OUTPUT)
    if (NOT SECOND_BOOST_TEST)
        message(FATAL_ERROR
                " Cannot compile. Something is wrong with your Boost installation.\n"
                " Output of test compile:\n"
                "${TRY_COMPILE_OUTPUT}")
    endif ()
    message(CHECK_PASS "Success")
endif ()

add_executable(main main.cpp)

if (NOT CORRECT_BOOST_VERSION)
    target_compile_options(main PRIVATE -isystem ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
else ()
    target_include_directories(main BEFORE PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif ()
```

```
// test_boost_version.cpp
#include <boost/version.hpp>
#ifndef BOOST_FOUND
#define BOOST_FOUND 0
#endif
static_assert(BOOST_VERSION == BOOST_FOUND); // BOOST_FOUND declared by CMake
int main() { return 0; }
```